# Passing variable in url using curl

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents

I Want to pass variable to the curl url but I am getting an error.
HELP ME

```
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/$id/comments?message=$messages&method=post&access_token=$m';
```

The code is:

```
$arr = file('comments.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); $messages = shuffle($arr); 
echo messages; 
$id = trim($_POST['post_id']); 
$url = 'graph.facebook.com/$id/…;; 
$curl_handle=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, '$url'); curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,200); curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
$send = curl_exec($curl_handle); curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the error ?

Comment: $arr = file('comments.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$messages = shuffle($arr);
echo messages;
$id = trim($_POST['post_id']);


$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/$id/comments?message=$messages&method=post&access_token=$m';

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, '$url');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,200);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$send = curl_exec($curl_handle);

curl_close($curl_handle);

Comment: Can you post that on your question instead ?

Answer (score 3):

you can pass all your variables in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, see the code below:

```
$ch = curl_init();                  
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/comments"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "message=some_msg&method=post&access_token=xyz"); // define what you want to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: yea !c it works .. but now getting problem with array messege array cant get random comments

Comment: $arr = file('comments.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$messages = shuffle($arr);

Comment: ok fine i  am awiting

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parameters from the URL and write following line to pass the Parameter in CURL,

```
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'your post parameters');
```

As your example, here is the code.

```
$arr = file('comments.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$messages = shuffle($arr);
echo messages;
$data = array("message"=>$messages,
"method"=>"post",
"access_token"=>$m
);


$id = trim($_POST['post_id']);
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/$id/comments';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,200);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POST,true);

curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$send = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: sorry i didnt get you

Comment: still error! i am unable to setup. can i send file to you ? you can do it ?

Comment: http://djliker.com/test.txt check this

Comment: sorry!http://machineliker.com/test.txt

Comment: Just write down, your $message, and $data array, and give it to me.

Answer (score 1):

The `shuffle()` returns a boolean value. So you will eventually get a true or false. Don't assign that to `$messages`.

Simply do this..

```
$arr = file('comments.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
shuffle($arr);
$data = array("message"=>implode('',$arr),
"method"=>"post",
"access_token"=>$m
);
```

Comment: i am getting array print in message

Comment: @user3563010, I modified the code.. Can you try now ?

Comment: bro that all setted method and accesstoken.. so now give me code for only comments.txt for saving in variable $messages thanks

Comment: Can you post what is there inside your `comments.txt` ?

Comment: its done bro! i am getting output now! thank you so much!

Comment: @user3563010, You need to accept the correct answer to this question and the previous question you asked as well.